# Не могу решить задачу с теории вероятностей

Tags: математика, теория-вероятностей

Партия изделий, среди которых **9 - первого сорта**, **6 - второго** и **3 - третьих сорта** случайным образом разбивается на **3 равные
части**. Найдите вероятность того, что изделия первого, второго и третьего сортов поделятся при этом **поровну**.
Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так...

Ставим в ряд 18 корзин, раскидываем все элементы случайно. Итого - 18!/(9!*6!*3!) = 4084080 способов их раскидать (факториалы в знаменателе - из-за неотличимости изделий в пределах сорта).

Теперь - сколько же у нас способов устраивающего нас разброса? Делим корзины на шестерки. В пределах шестерки - корзин для первого сорта - выбираем 6!/(3!*3!) способами, для второго сорта из оставшихся - 3!/(2!*1!) способами (думаю, догадались, что это числа сочетаний? :)) Оставшаяся корзина выбирается однозначно. Итого, перемножая - 60 способов. Для всех шестерок - 60*60*60 = 216000 способов.

Вероятность = 216000/4084080 ~0.0529...

На коленке набросанный эксперимент

```
int main()
{
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 g(rd());
    vector<int> v { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,100,100,100};
    unsigned long long total = 0, ok = 0;
    for(; total < 10000000;)
    {
        shuffle(v.begin(),v.end(),g);
        total++;
        int sum = v[0]+v[1]+v[2]+v[3]+v[4]+v[5];
        if (sum == 106)
        {
            sum = v[6]+v[7]+v[8]+v[9]+v[10]+v[11];
            if (sum == 106)
            {
                ok++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << double(ok)/total << "\n";
}
```

[вполне согласуется с теорией](https://ideone.com/HpGwaN).